# Initialising values for memory after dynamic allocation?

Tags: c, initialization, malloc

Im aware that `malloc()` returns a pointer to the initialised block of memory, but initialising this memory is difficult for me.

```
struct state{
    int one;
    int two;
};

struct state *one = malloc(sizeof(struct state));
*one = (struct state){.one = 10,.two = 20};
free(one);
```

Im aware that the above thing can be done to initialise a bunch of values for the structure without individually accessing the fields and changing the value manually.But can anyone explain how the above code works?

Also how can I do this for a pointer to several ints. The code below doesn't seem to work:

```
int *pointer = (int*) {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: In your second code fragment, you allocate memory from the heap to a pointer then you change the pointer which loses the allocated memory and then you attempt to free the second area of memory which was never allocated by you but was instead from the stack.

Comment: @Spaceghost I have changed my above code in my question,thanks but it still doesn't seem to work any ideas?

Comment: You changed it to be one line.  What is it that doesn't work?  Please post more code showing what you have attempted and a better explanation of what is wrong.  Even better, provide an explanation of what are you are trying to do and how you think your code achieves that

Comment: "...without individually accessing the fields"  But this is what your code does. Designated initializers is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

> can anyone explain how the above code works?

In the same way that the code below works:

```
int *one = malloc(sizeof(int));
*one = 1020;
free(one);
```

The only difference is that instead of assigning a numeric value your code assigns the value of the `struct`, expressed through a `struct` *aggregate*. Everything else is the same: the assignment copies the content of one region of memory into another region of memory.

> Also how can i do this for a pointer to several `int`s?

Use `memcpy`, like this:

```
int *pointer = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
static int data[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
memcpy(pointer, data, sizeof(data));
free(pointer);
```

Comment: Isn't `*one = 1020;` writing into the pointer itself, and not the actual array?

Comment: @Magisch No, dereference operator `*` has higher precedence than assignment operator `=`, so the value is assigned to whatever is pointed to by the pointer `one`.

Comment: But you assign the pointer to the very same thing in `int *one = malloc(sizeof(int));` In my understanding malloc() returns a pointer to a memory block. How is `*one = 1020;` not equivalent to `int *one = 1020;`?

Comment: @Magisch `int *one = ...` is not an assignment, it's declaration/initialization. The asterisk in `int *xyz` and simply `*xyz` by itself does *not* mean the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. Thanks for taking the time of explaining that to me. Im used to doing stuff like `int one = 1020;` as sort of declaration with assigning a value directly. Wasn't sure if pointers had the same syntax and didn't have the pleasure of using dynamic allocation yet.

Answer (score 2):

> But can anyone explain how the above code works?

I can explain what it *means*.

> ```
> struct state{
>     int one;
>     int two;
> };
> ```

That declares a structure type with tag `state`, which thereafter can be referenced via the type name `struct state`.

> ```
> struct state *one = malloc(sizeof(struct state));
> ```

That declares `one` as a pointer to an object of type `struct state`.  Supposing that the `malloc()` succeeds, it initializes `one` to point to a dynamically-allocated, uninitialized block of memory exactly the size of a `struct state` and aligned in a manner suitable for an object of that (or any other) type.

> ```
> *one = (struct state){.one = 10,.two = 20};
> ```

The right-hand side of that expression is a compound literal of type `struct state`.  The part inside the braces is its initialization list, exactly as you might use to initialize an ordinary variable of the same type:

```
struct state two = { .one = 10, .two = 20 };
```

The `.one` and `.two` name the member initialized by each individual initializer; they are optional in this particular case because in their absence, the initializer expressions would be matched to structure members in the order the members appear in the structure type declaration.  Overall, the statement copies the value of the literal struct to the object pointed-to by `one`.

> ```
> free(one);
> ```

That releases the dynamic memory block.

> Also how can i do this for a pointer to several ints[?]

There is no such thing as a pointer to several `int`s.  There is a pointer to *one* `int`, or a pointer to specific-size *array* of `int`s, but -- and I know I'm being pedantic here -- neither of those is "a pointer to several ints".

It looks like what you want in this case is an array, not (directly) a pointer.  You can initialize an array and set its size in one declaration, like so:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Afterward, you can use `array` in most respects as if it were a pointer to the first `int` in the array.

Note, however, that unlike structures, whole arrays cannot be assigned to.  Although the above code may look like it contains an assignment, it does not -- it contains an initializer.  Though the syntax is similar, initializers are not assignments.  The latter are executable statements; the former are not.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have a function (or macro if you're into those):

```
struct state{
    int one;
    int two;
};

struct state* alloc_state(int one, int two)
{
    struct state s = {one, two}; // order is per struct definition!
    struct state* p = malloc(sizeof(struct state));
    memcpy(p, &s, sizeof(s));
    return p;
}
```

This function will always stay 4 lines of code regardless of how many argument are used.
The same principle can be used with other types.

Macro version:

```
#define ALLOC_STATE(p, ...)   \
{                               \
    struct state s = {__VA_ARGS__}; \
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct state)); \
    memcpy(p, &s, sizeof(s));\
}
```

Usage:

```
struct state* p;
ALLOC_STATE(p, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(struct state){.one = 10,.two = 20};` is a compound literal. It is an object that remains valid until the end of the block scope.

```
*one = (struct state){.one = 10,.two = 20};
```

Is equivalent to

```
struct state temp = {.one = 10,.two = 20};
*one = temp;
```

In the second example, the definition of the compound literal is wrong, you must specify an array type, and then you point your pointer just like normal:

```
int *pointer = (int[]) {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Again this is equivalent to:

```
int temp[] =  {1,2,3,4,5} ;
int *pointer = temp;
```

Comment: Immediately after this `int *pointer = (int[]) {1,2,3,4,5};`  statement  `pointer` dangles, as the memory use by the compound `(int[]) {1,2,3,4,5};` is freed and *no* copying took place, as per the example assigning a `struct`!

Comment: @alk, not exactly.  The literal "has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block" (C2011, 6.5.2.5/5), so it lasts past the assignment statement, to the end of the innermost enclosing block.  (Or it would be static if it appeared at file scope, but that seems not to be the intended case here.)  Your point is nevertheless well made, however, for the eventual disappearance of the pointed-to array likely would take the OP by surprise.

Comment: @alk The pointer doesn't dangle. As I have written in the answer, compound literals exist until the end of the block. The second part of your comment is a strawman. OP specifically asked how to point a pointer to a compound literal (Take a look at the second part of OP's question: *Also how can I do this for a pointer to several ints...* ) and I have shown specifically that, and that part of the answer is clearly separated from the direct assignment part.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Alk's point is fallible because I have clearly pointed out the duration of the compound literal. If OP reads the entire answer, as he should, he cannot be surprised.

Comment: @this: Yes, I was wrong,  the pointer does not dangle immediately. Still I feel the two examples gave the impression they'd behave the same, in terms of "copying" data to the target, which it not the case for the latter example.